# Visually wrap/cycle items around in WPF container?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, word-wrap

I have a WPF/C# situation where I have a horizontal list of items and the user can navigate forward and backward through the list.

Assuming the list has 5 items, below are three mock-ups of the UI (initial, and after the user clicks the right arrow twice.

```
< [1] [2] [3] [4] >
< [2] [3] [4] [5] >
< [3] [4] [5] [1] >
```

So, basically, the list should scroll indefinitely in either direction.

There may be a significant number of items (50-150) in the list and will include images.  So my first thought would be that I need to use a VirtualizingStackPanel in the solution, but there may be other tracks to get this done without the need for one.

Now, to add to the complexity, the items must animate smoothly forwards and backwards.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dr. WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/Default.aspx) had a similar sample once [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/55/Default.aspx). Maybe you can adapt the idea.